# Angular edit row & store values in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, angular, typescript

I need to compare edited row data with the row just below edited row.

A table with 5 rows. When i am editing records from **top to bottom** in that order using below code i am able to store values that are edited in an array. Here latest edited value is stored at the last index of **storeArray**.

When i am editing records from **bottom to top**, the last edited record is now saved at 1st index but i want that there. It should also save the data like above i.e **last edited value should be present at last index in the array**

Similarly when it is edited in random order then also last edited value should be at last index of array.

Below is the code used to fetch and save edited values

```
 const storeArray = _.reduce(this.allValuesArray, function(storeArray, value, key) {
  return _.isEqual(value, this.allValuesArray[key]) ?
  storeArray : storeArray.concat(allValuesArray[key]);      
 }, []);
```

Above method is called after editing few rows when the button Save is clicked.

- allValuesArray = JSON having all row records fetched during ngOnInit
- storeArray = The array in which i am storing the data that are being edited

Everything is done on Angular 5

Comment: Can you share sample of `AllValuesArray` values?

Comment: sure @NimittShah
its similar to JSON Array of objects some what like this
                
`{"employees":[    
    {"name":"Ram", "email":"ram@gmail.com", "age":23},    
    {"name":"Shyam", "email":"shyam23@gmail.com", "age":28},  
    {"name":"John", "email":"john@gmail.com", "age":33},    
    {"name":"Bob", "email":"bob32@gmail.com", "age":41}   
]}  `

Comment: @NimittShah- is the row index of table creating problem?? like while editing TopToBottom it may be stroring data based on rowIndex, similarly reverse when editing BottomToTop/random order..

Comment: Why do you need `storeArray`? You can use `AllValuesArray` directly instead! ordering will not matter

Comment: AllValuesArray are having original data received from server but i need to store data after edit, hence AllValuesArray will not have data after edit @NimittShah...

Comment: Actually what I need is to compare the row edited with value just below that row..

Comment: See [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest)

Comment: @AEmilia What will be the `StoreArray` object after you edit first row? Can you please share! I mean are you adding new row or just editing the same one?

Comment: Not adding new row, after editing say 1st row.. That object array will store the row with new data at 1st index. Now after editing 2nd row it will store another row with new values at 2nd index. @NimittShah Now when I am editing in random order this order just gets changed

Answer (score 1):

You can try **reverse** method in the end to reverse the order of the elements in your array

```
storeArray.reverse();
```

Comment: Ok i can but how will i differentiate that this time row has been edited BottomToTop Or TopToBottom or random order?

Comment: Ur idea is correct is there any way i can check if its edited in BottomToTop Or TopToBottom or random order?